# What is a detox wing?

Tags: collocations

I had been reading this[article from a BBC podcast](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b087prhd) and they are referring to a detox wing.
It's not clear what "a detox wing" is?

I have some ideas in mind but I would like to be sure about it.

Comment: Your ideas are correct.

Comment: And they could have been corroborated by a simple [Google search](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=detox+wing&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=NeR9WOHdDuWm8weV-rywAg), no? Or had there been something more that you had been looking for and could not have been answered by a computer?

Comment: please could you point out in your simple Google search where "detox wing" is defined?

Comment: [Third link: Drug & Alcohol Detox Centers in Wing, AL - Facilities and Clinics](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0ahUKEwiS7qKP8cjRAhXGfbwKHTF3C_kQFgg3MAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.detoxlocal.com%2Fdetox-centers%2Fwing-al%2F&usg=AFQjCNFrN_l1yrFGxLKq4BRLqvJWqCCD0Q&sig2=V3rbnTrtd6YWrT19ZP4_sQ). Meanwhile, what had your ideas been?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang That's a Detox Centre in Wing, Alabama, not a "detox wing". In fact the top result for me is this question, not such a simple search after all.

Comment: @JameP They are the same thing....

Comment: No they aren't, one is part of a building, the other is a town in Alabama.

Comment: And my aim had been to allow Gyonder the opportunity to do some of her own research first, per the guidelines for [asking a good question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), but I had been open to getting the ball rolling for her.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, they are the same thing. Now, if I had been posting this as an official answer, I would highlight the difference between a wing and a center, but the two places serve the same essential purpose, no?

Comment: I had done some research. I just wanted to know what a "detox wing" is. Wing has several meanings. And apparently you don't know the meaning specified in the article yourself as you pointed out at a town in Alabama called Wing

Comment: @Teacher While searching the Internet can be useful, it's difficult to know that your understanding is correct when the results are written in the language you're learning. I think the question would be improved if Gyonder [edit]ed it to  explain what they were thinking it meant and what made them unsure it, but there is enough information here to make the question useful to other people and to write a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wing is part of a large building, usually extending from the main part. The term is commonly used in hospital and prison buildings.

The podcast is referring to a part of the prison that is primarily used to rehabilitate prisoners who are addicted to drugs.